# Trying to read in the files of a directory and write it to a list

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create 5000 junk files, write them to a file and delete them. But this code only is writing a portion of the files to the file. ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l says I have 1598 files remaining in the directory that is supposed to be emptied with unlink();. If I remove close(fd) I get a seg fault if I do any more than 1000 files. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>



main (int argv, char *args[]){
    if(argv<3){
        printf("Please run with proper command line arguements.\n");
        return;
    }
    int numFiles = atoi(args[1]);
    char *fileName = args[2];
    char *fileList[numFiles];
    int x, ret,fd;
    char buff[50];
    for(x=0;x<numFiles;x++){
        ret = sprintf(buff,"./stuff/%s-%d.junk",fileName, x);
        fd = creat(buff);
        close(fd);
    }
    DIR *odir = opendir("./stuff");        
    struct dirent *rdir = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("./files.list", "w");
    x=0;
    while(rdir = readdir(odir)){
        char* name = rdir->d_name;
        ret = sprintf(buff,"./stuff/%s-%d.junk",fileName, x);
        if(strcmp(name,"..")!=0){
            if(strcmp(name,".")!=0){
                fprintf(fp,"%s  %d\n",name,x);
                x++;
            }
        }
        unlink(buff);
    }
    close(fp);
    closedir(odir);
}
```

Thanks!

Note: Use of creat(), opendir(), readdir() and unlink() were required for the assignment. And as for error checking, your right of course but I'm under time constraints and the TA really, really doesn't care... But thank you all!

Comment: Add error checks, use perror when an error is returned and then come back with more information about what is failing if aren't able to sort it out yourself why it is failing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've be assigned to use creat(), opendir(), readdir() and unlink(). I love being taught depreciated functions! Now I've changed unlink(buff) to sprintf(buff, "./stuff/%s",name); unlink(buff) and everything works. Thanks for the help and suggestions all!

Comment: Check the result of those functions to ensure they have behaved correctly and then use perror if they haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing things from the directory while calling `readdir`; I *think* that's supposed to work OK, but you might want to consider avoiding it.

More to the point: as you iterate over the directory with `readdir` you're potentially removing different files from the ones `readdir` is listing. (Because what you pass to `unlink` is `buff` which you've filled in from the steadily-incrementing `x` rather than from anything returned by `readdir`.) So, here's a toy example to show why that's problematic. Suppose the directory contains files 1,2,3,4 and readdir lists them in the order 4,3,2,1.

- readdir tells you about file 4. You delete file 1.
- readdir tells you about file 3. You delete file 2.
- readdir would have told you about file 2, but it's gone so it doesn't.
- readdir would have told you about file 1, but it's gone so it doesn't.

You end up with files 3 and 4 still in the directory.

Comment: obviously readdir should work fine while files are being added or removed from the directory since there's no way to guarantee that some _other_ program isn't doing it. And how else would `rm -r` work? Anyway, the point is, the sprintf call should be `sprintf(buff,"./stuff/%s",name)`.

Comment: Obviously it should. But, e.g., there is no guarantee of whether a file that's added or deleted after calling `opendir` will be enumerated. And yes, the main point is that the file being removed is not the same one as the file enumerated by `readdir`, which is what I said.

Comment: This is the comment that saved the day. Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Here you're using `fopen`:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("./files.list", "w");
```

But then you're using `close` instead of `fclose` to close it:

```
close(fp);
```

I'm not at all sure this is what's causing the problem you're seeing, but it's definitely wrong anyway. You probably just want `unlink(rdir->d_name)` instead of `unlink(buff)`. You embedded the number into the file name when you created it -- you don't need to do it again when you're reading in the name of the file you created.

Comment: Yeah this is what I would typically do, not sure why I was assigned to use the other functions. But thanks anyways!

Comment: @Josh Gilbertson: If you're assigned to use `close`, that's fine -- but if you're going to, you need to use the matching `open` instead of `fopen`.